# How to make more friendly Facebook application which automatically get access token for user?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on Facebook application using facebook4j API, and it requires access token each time. I want to make this application more friendly with user, and get access token in automatically way.

So user will not have to go graph API explorer,and get access token from there each time. Also I want solution with Java only, no additional programming languages.

```
import facebook4j.Facebook;
import facebook4j.FacebookFactory;
import facebook4j.auth.AccessToken;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    facebook.setOAuthAppId("*****", "***********");
    facebook.setOAuthPermissions("user_friends,user_groups,user_photos,user_videos,user_birthday,user_status,user_likes,user_activities,user_location");
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken("*******", null));
    //do something




}

}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What did you try so far? Why does your code not work? Please elaborate on the problem and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the login dialog as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3

Answer (score 0):

After you get the access token, You can store it somewhere for accessing Facebook API later on. It's not a one-time token. It might be expired or revoked though. It can be stored in a session for web app or in memory for desktop app. In your case, you probably want to store it in your database and associate it to user's id. More details can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#token